# how to develop a drop down table search bar instead of drop down list in c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I'm trying to develop an autocomplete search bar similar to google but instead of list i do like to pop down a table with 4-5 columns and want to populate it from data extracting from database.
[pop-down suggestion table as shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDlOG.png)

Comment: What kind of code have you written so far?  What kind of environment (Windows Forms, WPF, something else)?

Comment: @Flydog57 i did made an auto suggest search bar but it only shows data on list view and i don't know how to replace that list from table